# Asp.net MVC load it via button rather than load it directly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently have working MVC app that directly loads data to html table, but my aim is to load it if I pressed a button of simply put the data on the table once the button is triggered.

Here is my current View
where my design is or index has been load:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@model IEnumerable<Entry.Models.util>

    @section Styles {
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    }

    <html>
    <body>     

        <div id="table-wrapper">
            <div id="table-scroll">
                <table border="1">

                    <tr>
                        <th>HeaderA</th>
                        <th>HeaderB</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%">@item.name</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink(
                             "Add",
                             "Add",
                             new { id = item.serial},
                             new
                             {
                                 @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign",
                                 onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to add " + @item.name + " to list ?');"
                             })

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is my Controller
where my query to mysql has been load:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {

            //Load list table from MySql
            List<util> myList = new List<util>();
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string query = "SELECT serial, name FROM tableA";
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                myList.Add(new util
                                {
                                    serial= Convert.ToInt32(sdr["serial"]),
                                    name = sdr["name"].ToString()
                                });
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            return View(myList);
        }
```

I tried to refer to this link but I'm net yet good at ORM method since I am new to this platform https://forums.asp.net/t/2006507.aspx?How+to+Load+Contents+from+table+only+after+click+a+button+

Any suggestion/comments. TIA

Comment: Start learning using `Forms` in MVC. It could be helpful.

Comment: You need to make an ajax call if you are wanting to stay on the same page and add to the DOM. Or are you wanting to redirect to another view? (its not really clear what you want to achieve)

Comment: You should try AJAX to do that. The `confirm` output can be used to decide if the AJAX callback to show other element(s) should be initiated.

Comment: could you give a example of that. Sorry I am very newbie to this platform just need some initial background